# Treeview in MS word

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, treeview

I have the following tree view in an access form (structure generated in visual basic using java), and I wish to save the full tree and view it in MS Word. Is this possible? Note that I don't need the treeview functionality so I am not looking for a treeview object in Word (unless that is available :-) in which case I need guidance on how to populate it using VBA); I only wish to view the full tree in Word in one ?picture? spanning multiple pages.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The TreeView is an ActiveX control, so it is available in Word. You can therefore create a word document, insert a TreeView control and clone the nodes from the existing. See below.

Call the method passing your existing control. You can set the `.Width` and `.Height` properties as you wish.

```
CloneTreeToWord YourTreeViewControl
```

---

```
Private Sub CloneTreeToWord(ByVal objTree As Object)
    On Error GoTo Trap
    
    'if error, do not leave orphan word app instances hanging around
    Dim failed As Boolean
    
    'create word app
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True
    
    'add blank doc
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    
    'insert a treeview to an inline shape
    Dim objShape As Object
    Set objShape = objWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2")
        objShape.Height = 600
        objShape.Width = 400
    
    'clone nodes
    Dim objWordTree As Object
    Set objWordTree = objShape.OLEFormat.Object
        objWordTree.Height = 600
        objWordTree.Width = 400
    Set objWordTree.ImageList = objTree.ImageList
    
    Dim xNode As Node, xNodeAdded As Node
    For Each xNode In objTree.Nodes
       If Not xNode.Parent Is Nothing Then
           'add child
           Set xNodeAdded = objWordTree.Nodes.Add(xNode.Parent.Key, tvwChild, xNode.Key, xNode.Text, xNode.Image, xNode.SelectedImage)
       Else
           'add node
           Set xNodeAdded = objWordTree.Nodes.Add(, , xNode.Key, xNode.Text, xNode.Image, xNode.SelectedImage)
       End If
       xNodeAdded.EnsureVisible
    Next
    
    'bring to front
    objWord.Activate
    
Leave:
    If Not failed Then Exit Sub
    If Not objDoc Is Nothing Then objDoc.Close 0 'wdDoNotSaveChanges
    If Not objWord Is Nothing Then objWord.Quit 0 'wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Exit Sub
    
Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    failed = True
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: OK so I can do some VBA stuff in Word too. But now I wish to connect to the access database and use the data in there to populate the treeview in Word. Do you have an example of how to do that too?

Comment: That's a different topic. You will need to ask a new question and probably provide sample data and how the data in the table is associated with the treeview nodes - are the column names same to the node text etc. You can link the question to this one.